# git packSizeLimit, msysgit default value is 2GB - why?

Tags: git, msysgit

Is there a particular reason behind setting git's packSizeLimit to 2GB by default in MSysGit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the default for `packSizeLimit`is unlimited, running `git gc`on large repos (something like 10 GiB in `.git`) will likely lead to "out of memory" errors, depending on your machine's memory configuration. That's why it was decided [to set sensible defaults](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/commit/5034631ff90bc088a51c3637ae8b8a7ba560875a).

Comment: Do you know by chance, why they set it exactly to 2GB? I've heard that packing takes around two times the memory of the file which would be 4GB and too much for a single Win32 process to be kept alive?!

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know why exactly 2GB. You would have to ask on the [msysgit mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit).

Comment: Tried to answer in that thread. To summarise: IMO, the default really tries to deal with with filesystems, like @CodeGnome hinted, rather than with memory; packing algorythm employs the so-called "window" in the memory which it uses to compare objects and generate deltas from them, and this window has three knobs to control its operation with one of them directly limiting the size of that window.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_GB_limit), some Win32 filesystems have a 2GB file size limitation. It also prevents garbage collection from using an excessive amount of RAM.